# Sign-in with Google button in a microservice-based architecture

Tags: google-oauth, microservices, google-signin

I have a microservice-based application that implements a dedicated user authentication and authorization service. This service has two API endpoints to login with Google: `GET signin` and `POST callback`. If `GET signin` is called, it will *challenge* the user by redirecting them to Google login, and after they sign in to Google, Google calls the `POST callback` API. The `POST callback` will sign in the user using the ID and access token it receives from Google, creates a local user, and returns its DTO.

I am trying to implement the `Sign in with Google` button in the UI. I am following [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/display-button) on creating this button. Here is what I have so far.

```
<html>
  <body>
      <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
      <script>
        window.onload = function () {
          google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "...",
            login_uri: "https://localhost:1234/signin",
            ux_mode: "redirect"
          });
          google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large", click_listener: onClickHandler }
          );
          
          function onClickHandler(){
            window.location.replace("https://localhost:1234/signin")
          }
          
          google.accounts.id.prompt();
        }
    </script>
    <div id="buttonDiv"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

This setup works, but not as expected.

The interaction I expect compared to what happens:

- User clicks on the `Login with Google` button;
- *[expect]* A pop-up opens and redirects to `https://localhost:1234/signin`. *[happens]* full-page redirect to `https://localhost:1234/signin`;
- `https://localhost:1234/signin` redirects to Google login;
- After the user sign in, `https://localhost:1234/callback` is called, which will sign in the user and redirects to the page where the `Sign in with Google` button was clicked.

I expect the redirect to happen in the pop-up, so the callback redirect happens in the pop-up, and user does not experience a full-page refresh. However, using the above code, two full-page refreshes happen: (a) redirect to the login endpoint, then to Google, (b) Google to the callback, then to the page where the login button was clicked.